I want to ask what is wrong with these multiple checkboxes not binding with the [checked] two way binding although the opt.checked is true
            <div style="display: table-caption" [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
                <div *ngFor="let opt of question.options; let i = index"  style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                    <!-- <mat-checkbox   [checked]="opt.checked">{{opt.value}}</mat-checkbox> -->
                    <mat-checkbox   [formControlName]="question.key"
                         style="padding-bottom: 12px;" #checkBox [checked]="opt.checked"
                        (change)="getCheckbox(checkBox)" [value]="opt.key" [name]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}
                    </mat-checkbox>
                </div>
            </div>

I want to ask what is wrong with these multiple checkboxex not binding with the [checked] two way binding although the opt.checked is true.
I want the checked boxes to be checked and when i exchange ngFor with formControl it works but i wont be able to validate when i check using angular dynamic forms

When you use a mat-checkbox with a FormControl you should not use checked (equals if you're using template driven form. You should manange the value througth the formControl
e.g.
  subtasks: [
      {name: 'Primary', completed: false},
      {name: 'Accent', completed: false},
      {name: 'Warn', completed: false},
    ],
  form=new FormGroup({
    Primary:new FormControl(false),
    Accent:new FormControl(false),
    Warn:new FormControl(false),
  })

And use:
<ul [formGroup]="form">
  @for (subtask of task.subtasks; track subtask) {
    <li>
      <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="subtask.name">
        {{subtask.name}}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </li>
  }
</ul>

The another way is use the property checked and the event change in the way
  <ul>
    @for (subtask of task.subtasks; track subtask) {
      <li>
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="form.get(subtask.name)?.value"
                      (change)="form.get(subtask.name)?.setValue($event.checked)">
          {{subtask.name}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>

a stackblitz like the example in angular using Reactive Forms. See that in the stackblitz there're two functions and a variable allComplete
  allComplete: boolean = false;

  someComplete(): boolean {
    return Object.keys(this.form.controls)
       .filter(key => this.form.get(key)?.value).length > 0 && 
                                          !this.allComplete;
  }

  updateAllComplete() {
    this.allComplete = Object.keys(this.form.controls)
       .filter(key => !this.form.get(key)?.value).length==0
  }

  //in setAll
  setAll(completed: boolean) {
    this.allComplete=completed //<--we add this line also
    this.subtasks.forEach(t => this.form.get(t.name)?.setValue(completed));
  }

To mannage the typical "selectAll"
